# Refactor a function that calculates freebies

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this method that takes in an array and returns an array of total of those items. This method calculates how many freebies you get when you order certain items. It works but looks like there's a lot of duplicate code. I was wondering, how can I best refactor this?

```
calculateFreebies(orders) {
  const freeItemAmount = [];
  const totalAmount = [];
  for (const order of orders) {

   const items = Math.floor(order.cash / order.price);
   const freebies = Math.floor(items / order.bonus_ratio);

   if (order.type === 'foo') {
       const bar = 0;
       const boo = 0;
       let foo = 0;
       foo = (foo + 1) * freebies;
       freeItemAmount.push({'\"foo\"': foo, '\"bar\"': bar, '\"boo\"' : boo});
       totalAmount.push({'\"foo\"': foo + items, '\"bar\"': bar, '\"boo\"' : boo});
      } else if (order.type === 'bar') {
         const foo = 0;
         const boo = 0;
         let bar = 0;
         bar = (bar + 2) * freebies;
         freeItemAmount.push({'\"foo\"': foo, '\"bar\"': bar, '\"boo\"' : boo});
         totalAmount.push({'\"foo\"': foo, '\"bar\"': bar + items, '\"boo\"' : boo});
        } else if (order.type === 'boo') {
         const bar = 0;
         let foo = 0;
         let boo = 0;
         foo = (foo + 1) *  freebies;
         boo = (boo + 1) *  freebies;
         freeItemAmount.push({'\"foo\"': foo, '\"bar\"': bar, '\"boo\"' : boo});
         totalAmount.push({'\"foo\"': foo, '\"bar\"': bar, '\"boo\"' : boo + items});
        }
  }
  return totalAmount;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create private functions for calculate the foo and boo variables. For example:

```
let foo = 0;
let boo = 0;
foo = (foo + 1) *  freebies;
boo = (boo + 1) *  freebies;
```

Replace to

```
let foo = calculatePrice(freebies);
let boo = calculatePrice(freebies);
```

And to create a objects (JSON)...

```
freeItemAmount.push(createItem(foo, bar, boo));
```

And if bar and boo always it's the same... put in the constant (in mayus)

```
freeItemAmount.push(createItem(foo, CONSTANT_BAR, CONSTANT_BOO));
```

etc...

Normally when you read the code that it's not by you, normally, you don't need understand all buniess technical (code). You only need understand buniess logical. For example:

```
for (const order of orders) {
    if (isFooProduct(order)) {
        freeItemAmount.put(createItem(...));
        totalAmount.put(createItem(...));
    else if (isBarProduct(order)) {
        ....
    }
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare the variables only once, not for every order type.

Then the push to the freeItemAmount array is the same for all three order types. That means you can push to the array after the if statements.

And lastly if you add the items directly to the variables you can do the same with the push to the totalAmount array.

```
    for (const order of orders) {
        const items = Math.floor(order.cash / order.price);
        const freebies = Math.floor(items / order.bonus_ratio);
        let bar = 0;
        let boo = 0;
        let foo = 0;

        if (order.type === 'foo') {
            foo = ((foo + 1) * freebies) + items;
        } else if (order.type === 'bar') {
            bar = ((bar + 2) * freebies) + items;
        } else if (order.type === 'boo') {
            foo = (foo + 1) * freebies;
            boo = ((boo + 1) * freebies) + items;
        }

        freeItemAmount.push({'\"foo\"': foo, '\"bar\"': bar, '\"boo\"' : boo});
        totalAmount.push({'\"foo\"': foo, '\"bar\"': bar, '\"boo\"' : boo});
    }
```